# Why does Qt discourage the localizing of images?

Tags: c++, image, qt, localization, resources

The Qt Linguist can be used to load different images depending on the language the application is running in. However, on the [Qt website](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/internationalization.html) it says

```
Localizing images is not recommended.
```

Why is it not recommended? I don't see the problem.

Comment: If you localize the images in - for example - buttons, a user that does not understand the language will not be able to use the application even in the most basic way. If you, as the manual recommends, use the same - clear - images for all languages, many operations will be clear to any user by just looking at the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for `Qt` specifically, but as a programmer in the games industry where we have to deal with many languages and "graphical" assets, the main problem with localizing images is that the process of localizing an image is way more complicated than having a string procedurally added on top of a generic "background" image.

Often, the translation companies will be dealing with `Excel` spreadsheets of strings to translate. If you're asking them to, for example, edit layers in Photoshop to add the translated text, I'm pretty sure your translating costs will explode.

So, overall, images CAN be localized, but it's rarely a good idea!